# How to set random seed in Galsim, the modular galaxy image simulation toolkit

Tags: galsim

How would one go about setting the random seed for functions like the following:

```
image = galsim.imageD(x_lim,y_lim,scale)
image_gal = gal_obj.drawShoot(image=image)
```

I need a deterministic seed but am not sure how to set it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "rng" keyword argument when drawing.  So for example, you could do

```
image = galsim.ImageD(x_lim, y_lim, scale=scale)
image_gal = gal_obj.drawShoot(image=image, rng=galsim.BaseDeviate(1234567))
```

if you want deterministic photon-shooting using the seed 1234567.

On a more minor note, use of drawShoot is still supported but is discouraged as of GalSim v1.1.  Instead, we are encouraging use of a unified drawing method that allows both photon-shooting and DFT rendering.  In that case, the last line of the code snippet would become

```
image_gal = gal_obj.drawImage(image=image, rng=galsim.BaseDeviate(1234567), method='phot')
```

(That is, assuming you have GalSim v1.1 installed.)

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out using the BaseDeviate classes and realized drawShoot wouldn't work with it!